# Issue in integrating ZXing to iphone App

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode4, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to develop QRCode reader application in iPhone.
I am trying to use ZXing SDK. i have successfully run the sample application given by ZXing. But i ma trying to develope new application as per instructions in Readme given by Zxing. but when i am trying to add ZxingWidget in build phases. it going add but it shows like below[image]

I think it will getting problem to me. When i am trying to run application it will give erros like Lexical or Prepocessor issue File not found.

Is am doing any thing wrong when am added to files to application. 
Actaully first of all i added ZxingWidget.xcodeproj to my application by drag and drop. But it wont give any alert window would you like copy like similar when we adding images or files to xcode. and next i added cpp and iphone folders to xcode application. and later i added the frameworks as per read me.
Please any one help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the exact errors that you are getting

Comment: Thanks @Vin for your response. I am getting Just one line only error like Lexical or Prepocessor error  File name not found. In this way i am getting 4 erros right now. I am assuming i made any mistake when adding files to my application

Comment: not sure if this will help but did you remember to change the extension of the file from where you're initianing ZXing from .m to .mm?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard to help without the real error message. In the Issue Navigator, you can Right Click > Reveal in Log to see the complete error that you can copy and paste.

That said, it sounds a bit like it can't find the headers (though I'm just guessing without the real error message.) If so, double check steps 4 and 5 of the [readme](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/iphone/README).

Answer (score 0):

if you run on real device, the problem will be solved.
I don't know the reason.
But I guess It's related to Build Products Path.